# delete elements from deque containing maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, deque

I have a deque containing map and I am trying to delete an element by map key.

That was my try, but it is not working:

```
typedef map<string,string> mmap;
deque<mmap> q_map;



int main()
{
    mmap m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair("S180","11111111111"));

    q_map.push_back(m);
    std::cout << q_map.front().find("S180")->first << " " << q_map.front().find("S180")->second << std::endl;

    q_map.erase(std::remove(q_map.begin(), q_map.end(), q_map.front().find("S180")->first), q_map.end());
    std::cout << "=================================" << std::endl;


}
```

I am always getting this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_Deque_iterator<std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >*>’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, which gives you the error message, is that you've likely forgotten to `#include <algorithm>` where `std::remove` is declared. Consequently you're accidentally trying to call a function with the same name but different parameters in `<cstdio>`.

The second problem is that your call to `std::remove` does not match to the one in `<algorithm>` either. It's declared like this:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt remove( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
```

And because the `T` of your deque iterator is `mmap`, you must pass a reference to `mmap` to remove all mmaps that have equal value. Instead you're passing `q_map.front().find("S180")->first` which is a `std::string`.